# Google geocoding without a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geocoding

I am attempting to implement an input element for geocoding without a button. i.e. the user begins to type in an address and then selects the wanted address from a list of Google suggested ones

In my Javsacript code, I load the following to enable the geocoding for my input element:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

This provides a set of dropdowns from the input field of potential addresses. When an address is selected by down arrow and then Enter is pressed, I use the following to capture the Enter key and perform the geocode (rather than using a button).

```
// capture enter on address input selection
  $("#pac-input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      geocode();
    }
  });
```

However, I would also like to capture the click of the mouse on one of the potential dropdown fields. I am using the following to capture all mouse clicks

```
// capture event for mouse click or ipad input
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($(this));
    var target = $(e.target);
    console.log(target[0]);
  });
```

This function definitely works as I see console activity on mouse clicks, such as:

```
[document, context: document]
<input id=​"pac-input" class=​"form-control" type=​"text" placeholder=​"Enter a location" autocomplete=​"off">​
```

However, on clicking one of the dropdown fields provided by the Google JS, I see **no console log**. What is happening here?

Edit: I do now see console output. But using

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($(this));
    var target = e.target;
    console.log(target);
});
```

I see `<body role="document">..</body>`. Not much of an identifier..

Comment: You are correct, but with target, I only get <body role="document">..</body> when I click on the Google suggested addresses dropdown. This is with a Chrome restart - something must have gone screwy when I was not seeing any console logs.

Comment: `target` should be `var target = e.target;` then `target` is your Element. Why do you want `target[0]`? That's why it doesn't show up in the console anyways. If you want dynamic geocoding you're going to have to use some kind of Event. `navigator.geolocation.watchPostion()` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `target` is `<body role="document">..</body>` because that's what you've attached the event handler to - `$(document)` is all very well for trapping all mouse clicks, but it means the event has to bubble all the way up before getting handled.

Why not use the inbuilt event handler for Google's `autocomplete`? From this [example](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/map-tips-get-started-with-autocomplete.html):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autoComplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry) {
     map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
     map.setZoom(15);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this - I have some reworking in my code once autocomplete occurs but this works on Chrome with both mouse and enter key selection & also on iOS for touch events!